# How to obtain difference of sets like behaviour with OOP

Tags: .net, friend, set-difference

I need a behaviour similar to the set-theory's difference operator `\`.
I am trying to get something of a `friend` class behaviour since i have the following situation:

```
    public interface IRead
    {
        List<string> GetInnerResource();
    } 
    public interface IWrite()
    { 
        bool SetInnerResource();
    }
    public interface IFull:IRead,IWrite{
        void SomeMethod();
    }


public Consumer:IFull  // IFull \ IWrite
{
   private IFull access; // IFull\IWrite 

   public List<string> GetInnerResource()=>this.access.GetInnerResource();
   public void SomeMethod()=>this.acces.SomeMethod();  // i need this 
   public bool SetInnerResource(){...}//--i do not want this here !
}
public Admin:IFull
{
   private IFull access;
   public List<string> GetInnerResource()=>this.access.GetInnerResource();
   public bool SetInnerResource()=>this.access.SetInnerResource();
   public void SomeMethod()=>this.access.SomeMethod();
}
```

As you can see i have `3` interfaces (`IRead`,`IWrite`,`IFull`) where the third one is derived from the first `2` and has another method.

I have two classes `Consumer` and `Admin` where:

```
 -Consumer needs to implement IFull \ IWrite
 -Admin  needs IFull
```

Since both my concrete classes delegate the implementations to an inner field 
the problem lies in the inner field for the `Consumer` class since it needs `something` that implements  `IFull\IWrite`

Normally in `C++` i would've solved this with a `friend` class that has full access to the class while using a `Read` for all others.Here i can't do this.

What are my alternatives ?
I need an interface `ISomething: {IFull\IWrite}` for the `Consumer` class

**P.S** `IFull\IWrite=IRead + [methods defined only in IFull]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and simple solution would be to break up the hierarchy from IFull interface and have 3 separate interfaces, which can be derived according to use need for either Consumer or Admin classes